# uiviewcontroller with navigation bar does not display searchBar in navigation bar

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationbar, searchbar, searchdisplaycontroller

I have a UIViewController with NavigationBar. I'm trying to place a searchBar in it with the following code:

```
self.searchDisplayController.displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar=YES;
```

The code has worked on my previous UIViewController, the difference is that one is embedded in a NavigationController where this is a modal segue, thus the need to manually place the NavigationBar in it.

What am I missing to get this to display in the NavigationBar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add serchbar on navigation bar like that:

```
mySearchBar.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, -80.0, 320.0, 44.0);
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:mySearchBar];
```